# How to find 2 special elements in the array in O(n)

Tags: algorithm

Let `a1,...,an` be a sequence of real numbers. Let `m` be the minimum of the sequence, and let `M` be the maximum of the sequence.

I proved that there exists 2 elements in the sequence, `x,y`, such that `|x-y|<=(M-m)/n`.

Now, is there a way to find an algorithm that finds such 2 elements in time complexity of `O(n)`?

I thought about sorting the sequence, but since I dont know anything about `M` I cannot use radix/bucket or any other linear time algorithm that I'm familier with.

I'd appreciate any idea.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know M and m? Solution could be something like sorting the elements into buckets and also storing min and max element of each bucket.

Comment: @Sebastian No, I dont.

Comment: Okay, finding min and max takes O(n), use n+1 buckets of size (M-m)/n. If there are two elements in one bucket, you have a match, otherwise it would be max of one bucket and min of the following one. You could check in a second run. You would stay below O(n).

Comment: @Sebastian You should post that as an answer, since it's the simplest solution.

Comment: @Sebastian Can you elaborate? how do you map the elements into the buckets and what guarantees that 2 of them would be mapped to the same bucket?

Comment: @FreeZe In case you have two different accounts (?), for clarity, it is better not using both them in the same post.

Comment: Note that the real threshold should be `(M-m)/(n-1)` !

Comment: @ksquared I have formulated the proposed way as answer. Thank you for asking.

Comment: Damien is right. If you have the sequence [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] you have 5 elements, but no two elements are closer than (4-0)/5 = 4/5. With the right threshold (M-m)/(n-1) the solution is easy - use (n-1) buckets of this size, and one bucket must have two values in it.

Answer (score 2):

1. First find out `n`, `M`, `m`. If not already given they can be determined in `O(n)`.
2. Then create a memory storage of `n+1` elements; we will use the storage for `n+1` buckets with width `w=(M-m)/n`.
   The buckets cover the range of values equally: Bucket `1` goes from `[m; m+w[`, Bucket `2` from `[m+w; m+2*w[`, Bucket `n` from `[m+(n-1)*w; m+n*w[ = [M-w; M[`, and the `(n+1)th` bucket from `[M; M+w[`.
3. Now we go once through all the values and sort them into the buckets according to the assigned intervals. There should be at a maximum 1 element per bucket. If the bucket is already filled, it means that the elements are closer together than the boundaries of the half-open interval, e.g. we found elements `x, y` with `|x-y| < w = (M-m)/n`.
4. If no such two elements are found, afterwards `n` buckets of `n+1` total buckets are filled with one element. And all those elements are sorted.
   We once more go through all the buckets and compare the distance of the content of neighbouring buckets only, whether there are two elements, which fulfil the condition.
   Due to the width of the buckets, the condition cannot be true for buckets, which are not adjoining: For those the distance is always `|x-y| > w`.

(The fulfilment of the last inequality in 4. is also the reason, why the interval is half-open and cannot be closed, and why we need `n+1` buckets instead of `n`. An alternative would be, to use `n` buckets and make the now last bucket a special case with `[M; M+w]`. But `O(n+1)=O(n)` and using `n+1` steps is preferable to special casing the last bucket.)

The running time is `O(n)` for step 1, `0` for step 2 - we actually do not do anything there, `O(n)` for step 3 and `O(n)` for step 4, as there is only `1` element per bucket. Altogether `O(n)`.

This task shows, that either sorting of elements, which are not close together or coarse sorting without considering fine distances can be done in `O(n)` instead of `O(n*log(n))`. It has useful applications. Numbers on computers are discrete, they have a finite precision. I have sucessfuly used this sorting method for signal-processing / fast sorting in real-time production code.

About @Damien 's remark: The *real* threshold of `(M-m)/(n-1)` is provably true for every such sequence. I assumed in the answer so far the sequence we are looking at is a special kind, where the stronger condition is true, or at least, for all sequences, if the stronger condition was true, we would find such elements in `O(n)`.

If this was a small mistake of the OP instead (who said to have proven the stronger condition) and we should find two elements `x, y` with `|x-y| <= (M-m)/(n-1)` instead, we can simplify:

1. -- 3. We would do steps 1 to 3 like above, but with `n` buckets and the bucket width set to `w = (M-m)/(n-1)`. The bucket `n` now goes from `[M; M+w[`.

For step 4 we would do the following alternative:

`4./alternative:` `n` buckets are filled with one element each. The element at bucket `n` has to be `M` and is at the left boundary of the bucket interval. The distance of this element `y = M` to the element `x` in the `n-1th` bucket for every such possible element `x` in the `n-1th`bucket is: `|M-x| <= w = (M-m)/(n-1)`, so we found `x` and `y`, which fulfil the condition, q.e.d.

Answer (score 1):

First note that the real threshold should be `(M-m)/(n-1)`.

The first step is to calculate the min `m` and max `M` elements, in O(N).

You calculate the `mid = (m + M)/2`value.

You concentrate the value less than `mid` at the beginning, and more than `mid` at the end of he array.

You select the part with the largest number of elements and you iterate  until very few numbers are kept.

If both parts have the same number of elements, you can select any of them. If the remaining part has much more elements than `n/2`, then in order to maintain a O(n) complexity, you can keep only`n/2 + 1` of them, as the goal is not to find the smallest difference, but one difference small enough only.

As indicated in a comment by @btilly, this solution could fail in some cases, for example with an input `[0, 2.1, 2.9, 5]`. For that, it is needed to calculate the max value of the left hand, and the min value of the right hand, and to test if the answer is not `right_min - left_max`. This doesn't change the O(n) complexity, even if the solution becomes less elegant.

Complexity of the search procedure: O(n) + O(n/2) + O(n/4) + ... + O(2) = O(2n) = O(n).

Comment: How are you defining density here?

Comment: @kcsquared I was defining the  density as the  number of values in a given  value interval divided by the total number of values in this index interval (n/2, then n/4 etc.). However, I don't think that this algorithm is working. I will delete this answer soon. I would have deleted it already if you did not ask this question !

Comment: There's a similar divide and conquer algorithm that does work using quickselect. Then, you divide the array in two parts around the median, rather than by index.

Comment: The algorithm works, but it is not as fast as you claim.  What if all of the numbers are close?  Then you'll keep dividing, dividing, dividing, and keeping all numbers each time!

Comment: @kcsquared It is what I am currently writing !

Comment: @btilly If the remaining part is much larger than `n/2`, then you are not obliged to keep all elements. Keeping *at least* `n/2` elements is enough. OP doesn't ask for the min difference, only for a difference small enough.

Comment: @Damien Yes, but you have to actually write that logic or it won't be fast.  Also the procedure as written doesn't quite work.  What if `n` is even, and it is an even split? Which half to take?  You will need the largest value under the median, and the smallest value over it to decide between left, right, or the gap crosses the median.  I realized that after my first comment.

Comment: @btilly I tried to detail my answer. I don't understand what you mean by *You will need the largest value under the median...*. I don't use the median value, but the middle one (OK, term *mid* is confusing). Moreover, we need to find a difference less *or equal* a threshold. In case an element is exactly equal to the middle value, we can keep it whatever the part which is selected.

Comment: @Damien Consider the array `[0, 2.1, 3.9, 5]`.  The only pair fitting the condition is `(2.1, 3.9)`.  Your algorithm, as currently described, will fail to find it.

Comment: @btilly In your example, `(M-N)/n=5/4=1.25;`. The only pair is `(3.9, 5)`. But I now understand what you mean. It will fail with `[0, 2.1, 2.9, 5]`. Looking for min and max of the two half segments will not modify the O(n) complexity, but it makes the solution less interesting effectively. I will modify the answer. Maybe not so worth keeping it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Damien is correct in his comment that the correct results is that there must be x, y such that |x-y| <= (M-m)/(n-1). If you have the sequence [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] you have 5 elements, but no two elements are closer than (M-m)/n = (4-0)/5 = 4/5.

With the right threshold, the solution is easy - find M and m by scanning through the input once, and then bucket the input into (n-1) buckets of size (M-m)/(n-1), putting values that are on the boundaries of a pair of buckets into both buckets. At least one bucket must have two values in it by the pigeon-hole principle.